# sun.security.tools.keytool.Main killing the Application Server (Wildfly 10) Process if it fails

Tags: java, wildfly, keytool

I am using sun.security.tools.keytool.Main class to add certificates on run time. It works perfectly when everything go right. However, when the command fails, it shuts down the entire application server.

Why is this happenning? and Would it be possible to avoid this? And only print a error message.

This is one of the commands I ran with sun.security.tools.keytool.Main

```
    public static void extractCertificate(String keystoreName, String password) {
       String command = "-export "+
                     "-keystore "+ AppServerAddresses.getSERVER_CONFIGURATION()+keystoreName+" "+
                     "-alias default "+
                     "-storepass "+password+" "+
                     "-file "+AppServerAddresses.getSERVER_CONFIGURATION()+"certificate.cer";
       execute(command);
   }

    public static void execute(String command){
     try{
        Class<?> cl;
        try {
            // java 6 and 7
            cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass("sun.security.tools.Keytool");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // java 8
            cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass("sun.security.tools.keytool.Main");
        }

        printCommand(command);
        Method main = cl.getMethod("main", new String[0].getClass());
        main.invoke(null, (Object) parse(command));
     } catch (Exception ex){
        Logger.getLogger(AppServer.class.getName()).log(Level.WARNING, null, ex);
     }
   }
```

and this is the outpot of the logs

```
2018-03-12 16:04:35,438 INFO  [stdout] (default task-52) keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Certificate not imported, alias <default> already exists

2018-03-12 16:04:35,445 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Thread-2) WFLYSRV0220: Server shutdown has been requested via an OS signal
```

I am using Java 8 and Wildlfy 10. Running on Windows 7

Thank you

Comment: Why? You can do it all with the `KeyStore` class. You don't need to run the entire tool, or put up with its behaviour on error.

Comment: That is true! I ended up removing this implementation and implementing all my methods with KeyStore class. Thank you!